# Symfony UserProviderInterface and security provider entity

Tags: symfony

As soon as I remove the `property:username` from my security.yml I can not login via the form.

Only error seeing:

```
Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.
```

Where could I start debugging?

From `app/logs/dev.log` I get

```
security.INFO: Authentication request failed: The Doctrine repository
"Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository" must implement UserProviderInterface.
```

What does that mean?

This is what I've got so far following http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

security.yml

```
security:
    providers:
        administrators:
            entity: { class:AcmePasswordBundle:User, property: username }

    encoders:
        Acme\PasswordBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            #cost: 12

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        admin_area:
            anonymous: ~
            pattern: .*
            form_login:
                login_path: acme_password_login
                check_path: acme_password_login_check
                target_path_parameter: _target_path
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/free, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Entity\User.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\PasswordBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
    }

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $username
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.1.0)<br/>
     * String representation of object
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.serialize.php
     * @return string the string representation of the object or null
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.1.0)<br/>
     * Constructs the object
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.unserialize.php
     * @param string $serialized <p>
     * The string representation of the object.
     * </p>
     * @return void
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the roles granted to the user.
     *
     * <code>
     * public function getRoles()
     * {
     *     return array('ROLE_USER');
     * }
     * </code>
     *
     * Alternatively, the roles might be stored on a ``roles`` property,
     * and populated in any number of different ways when the user object
     * is created.
     *
     * @return Role[] The user roles
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_ADMIN');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the salt that was originally used to encode the password.
     *
     * This can return null if the password was not encoded using a salt.
     *
     * @return string|null The salt
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Removes sensitive data from the user.
     *
     * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
     * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the user's account has expired.
     *
     * Internally, if this method returns false, the authentication system
     * will throw an AccountExpiredException and prevent login.
     *
     * @return bool true if the user's account is non expired, false otherwise
     *
     * @see AccountExpiredException
     */
    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the user is locked.
     *
     * Internally, if this method returns false, the authentication system
     * will throw a LockedException and prevent login.
     *
     * @return bool true if the user is not locked, false otherwise
     *
     * @see LockedException
     */
    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the user's credentials (password) has expired.
     *
     * Internally, if this method returns false, the authentication system
     * will throw a CredentialsExpiredException and prevent login.
     *
     * @return bool true if the user's credentials are non expired, false otherwise
     *
     * @see CredentialsExpiredException
     */
    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the user is enabled.
     *
     * Internally, if this method returns false, the authentication system
     * will throw a DisabledException and prevent login.
     *
     * @return bool true if the user is enabled, false otherwise
     *
     * @see DisabledException
     */
    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }
}
```

Entity\UserRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\PasswordBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
{

    /**
     * Loads the user for the given username.
     *
     * This method must throw UsernameNotFoundException if the user is not
     * found.
     *
     * @param string $username The username
     *
     * @return UserInterface
     *
     * @see UsernameNotFoundException
     *
     * @throws UsernameNotFoundException if the user is not found
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $q = $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('username', $username)
            ->setParameter('email', $username)
            ->getQuery();

        try {
            // The query::getSingleResult() method throws an exception
            // if there is no record matching the criteria.
            $user = $q->getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException $e) {
            $message = sprintf(
                'Unable to find an active admin AcmePasswordBundle:User object identified by "%s".',
                $username
            );
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message, 0, $e);
        }
        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Refreshes the user for the account interface.
     *
     * It is up to the implementation to decide if the user data should be
     * totally reloaded (e.g. from the database), or if the UserInterface
     * object can just be merged into some internal array of users / identity
     * map.
     *
     * @param UserInterface $user
     *
     * @return UserInterface
     *
     * @throws UnsupportedUserException if the account is not supported
     */
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $class = get_class($user);
        if(!$this->supportsClass($class)) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf(
                    'Instances of "%s" are not supported.',
                    $class
                )
            );
        }
        return $this->find($user->getId());
    }

    /**
     * Whether this provider supports the given user class.
     *
     * @param string $class
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $this->getEntityName() === $class
            || is_subclass_of($class, $this->getEntityName());
    }

}
```

Thanks for advices and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show how your Entity is configured, but you need to tell Doctrine to use your custom repository for the `User` entity. In annotations, this looks like:

```
 @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Vendor\Project\Entity\UserRepository")
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I'll update my question. I used `yml` and `xml` annotations. Trying to understand your answer but not really getting it..

Comment: Doctrine won't automatically pick up that the `UserRepository` is supposed to be used a the repository for `User` classes, you have to configure it to do so.

Comment: Where and how can I configure it to do so?

Comment: See here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Comment: That did the trick! I was looking all over the place... Thanks for the link. All I had to change was in `User.orm.xml` to add the `repository-class` as you mentioned: `<entity name="Acme\PasswordBundle\Entity\User" repository-class="Acme\PasswordBundle\Entity\UserRepository">`

Comment: Interesting.  I never realized that the entity provider would use the repository if it implements the UserProviderInterface.  I'll tweak my answer.  I'm more used to making a stand alone user provider and injecting the repository in as a service.  Avoids cluttering up the repository.  But still good to know.

Answer (score 2):

Update:  I was not aware that the entity user provider would work directly with the repository if the repository also implements the UserProviderInterface.

Here is an alternative using a UserProvider service.

Details are in: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html

Make a standalone user provider

```
class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $userRepository;

    public function __construct($userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    $q = $this->userRepository->  // This is the only difference
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :email')
        ->setParameter('username', $username)
        ->setParameter('email', $username)
        ->getQuery();

    try {
        // The query::getSingleResult() method throws an exception
        // if there is no record matching the criteria.
        $user = $q->getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException $e) {
        $message = sprintf(
            'Unable to find an active admin AcmePasswordBundle:User object identified by "%s".',
            $username
        );
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message, 0, $e);
    }
    return $user;
}
// Rest of user provider functions
```

Wire up with:

```
# security.yml
providers:
    acme_password_user_provider:
        id: acme_password.user_provider

        form_login:
            provider:            acme_password_user_provider
            login_path:          acme_password_login

# services.yml


acme_password.user_repository:
    class:  Acme\PasswordBundle\Entity\UserRepository
    factory_service: 'doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'
    factory_method:  'getRepository'
    arguments:  
        - 'Acme\PasswordBundle\Entity\User'

acme_password.user_provider:
    class:  Acme\PasswordBundle\Security\UserProvider
    arguments: ['@acme_password.user_repository']
```

And of course, like @AlpineCoder said, you need to ensure that your repository is connected to your entity:

```
# User.orm.yml
Acme\PasswordBundle\Entity\User:
    type:  entity
    table: users
    repositoryClass: Acme\PasswordBundle\Entity\UserRepository
```

But the main point is to define the user provider as a service.

Comment: Oooh, thank you! I was thinking about services ... hmm now this needs a bit more time to study .. will get back to it!

Comment: I updated my answer.  Using an entity provider is perfectly valid.  The service approach is more flexible as it's not tied directly to the repository.

Comment: What means "in your case, your user repository is also the provider"? There are a few more chapters I have to go trough to get to the mentioned custom_provider chapter... I just don't know enough yet to talk about it :( like why should I in this case create a service if it works without?

Comment: I updated my answer again showing how you can split the UserProvider into it's own class and inject the repository.  Why do such a thing?  Some might argue it's a cleaner design to have the security stuff broken out.  It's a bit more flexible if you need additional services for your user provider.  However, for your specific use case, it's perfectly fine to stay with the entity user provider.  I only wrote this answer because I had not realized that the entity provider would work.  Keeping it here for my documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort! I will accepct AlpineCoders answer cause it answered my question. In a month or so I'll probably need your answer to set up those services...